# How to sanitize text for SQL upload to a database using R and RJDBC?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I have a R script that is taking some some user input, and scraping some data from webpages, etc.  Then it's doing some small manipulations and INSERTing the text to a table on a MS SQL Server.  The text blocks are up to 10,000 characters possibly more (using VARCHAR(MAX) columns).

If I was on MySQL or something i'd use Hadley's new packages that sanitize inputs, but I'm stuck on Microsoft.  So I'm using  `gsub`  to pull out single-quotes, and apostrophes, but it's pretty slow.  Is there a package that will do this quickly, and is there a better practice for stripping all naughty characters/strings from SQL inputs, so I can avoid the [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) problem?  I've found a few formulations in other languages, but nothing that is clean and fast in R.